# Is it possible to enter regular text password on htaccess UI and Apache encrypt and compare?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, encryption

I am using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.

Is there any way to keep the encrypted password in .htpasswd file ,
but user can enter regular text and Apache encrypt and compare .

Is it possible , just like a database check done by PHP or we have to enter the same password as in .htpasswd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an `.htpasswd` file with the `htpasswd` command line utility, the stored passwords *are* being crypted/hashed. You then enter the plaintext password into the UI, and Apache will hash that the same way and compare it to the hashed password in the `.htpasswd` file. Soooo.... it already works like you want it to.

See the manual: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html

Comment: I was missing the command line execution. I was just creating htpasswd file and moved it. When i create file using cmd it works. Thanks